# Extract data from html page using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="name">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <strong>
    <a target="_blank" href="/page3.html">
      SOME_Name_TEXT
    </a>
  </strong>
</div>

<div class="data">
  <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
  &nbsp; SOME_Data_TEXT
</div>
```

I have a html page with the different classes. I am able to extract class "name" and "data" from different classes using beautifulsoup

```
myName = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "name"})
myData = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "data"})
```

But the result I get when I run the script and print myName and myData elements respectively:

```
Â Â SOME_Name_TEXT(as a link)
Â SOME_Data_TEXT
```

The problem is I dont want Â. This is due to 
2 `&nbsp;`'s in first and one in second.

I just want the result as:

```
SOME_Name_TEXT(as a link)
SOME_Data_TEXT
```

In the first part link with the "SOME_Name_TEXT" is required.
Image in data part is not needed, I want just the raw text in second part i.e "SOME_Data_TEXT". I tried doing it using str.split(). How can I get the exact results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it with the help of other questions:

For the first part i.e

```
<div class="name">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
      <strong>
        <a target="_blank" href="/page3.html">
          SOME_Name_TEXT
        </a>
      </strong>
    </div>
```

Let this block is in x, then I used `print x.findNext('strong')`
And for 2nd part i.e.

```
<div class="data">
  <img src="/page1/page2/Images/pic.png" height="13" width="13">
  &nbsp; SOME_Data_TEXT
</div>
```

I did like:

```
tmp = x.findNext('img')
print tmp.get_text().strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want &nbsp, you can do something like this:

```
myName = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "name"})
myData = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "data"})
if(myName && !soup.findAll(text="&nbsp;"))
{
    System.out.print(myName);
}
```

or 2nd approach, here str is your myName:

```
str= "&nbsp; hey how are you doing"
str.decode("utf-8");
str = str.replace("&nbsp;", "")
print str
```

Comment: No, I want the data without "&nbsp;". I dont want to loose any result.
I tried str.replace("&nbsp;", ""); 
It didn't work.

Comment: the second approach won't work if BS is converting the entity to unicode.

Comment: Add utf-8 as character set @Arewegood as 2nd approach works for me.

Comment: @fscore: it is not working again. Dont know what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Arewegood upload the webpage to some site and send me link to test it properly

Comment: @Arewegood how is your soup object? please paste the entire code before that

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a unicode replace to remove the `&nbsp;` because BS converts HTML entities to unicode characters.

```
Edit:
soup.prettify(formatter=lambda x: x.replace(u'\xa0', ''))
```

Other options: For myData, to just get the text, do this:

```
myData = soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "data"})[0].find('img').contents[0].strip()
```

and for myName:

```
myName = repr(soup.findAll("div", {"class" : "name"})[0].find('a'))
myName = re.sub(' ', '', myName)
```

does that work for you?

Comment: I am getting the Error:
`<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 22: ordinal not in range(128) `

Comment: Sorry but it is still not working. No change in result.

Comment: what version of BS are you using?

Comment: Ok try the new edit using the strip() method. If that works, then you should be able to follow the same procedure on "myName"